# Can we have Azure SDK 1.8 with CCProj (Azure CCProj)

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have one small Question on Azure SDK 1.8 *.ccproj. Previously we are working SDK 1.7 Azure Project. Now we want to upgrade to 1.8 since azure SDK 1.8 is going to break changes of existing 1.7 sdk code. Can we have 1.8 version *.ccproj with all csdef and csconf file changes according to 1.8 and have StorageClient  and ServiceRuntime, Diagnostics and Configuration dll's of 1.7 version. I did these changes, and deployed the package. Though package got deployed successfully but it did not started running, it fails to start. Is it because of different version assembly, Azure services fails to start. Has any one tried with this approach before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm,

Correctly if I'm wrong, but the only **major** difference between 1.7 and 1.8 is the Storage Client library. I don't recall any other **braking change**, do you?

However if you take a closer look you have two flavors of Storage Client Library that come with Azure SDK 1.8. One is the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` assembly with version **2.0.0.0** (the one that comes with the SDK!). There is however one more: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll` assembly with version **1.7.0.0**.

While the former is installed in GAC (v. 2.0.0.0), the latter (1.7.0.0) is in the SDK folder: `%programfiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-10\bin`

And the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.7.0.0 assembly **that comes with SDK 1.8** is fully compatible with the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime 1.8. The Diagnostics Manager also is versioned 1.8.0.0 so you have to reference this version in your project.

I've deployed number of project developed on SDK 1.8 with StorageClient 1.7.0.0 (**the one that from SDK 1.8 folder**) in Windows Azure without any issues!

The correct way of upgrading your project is via the `Properties` windows of the Cloud Project:

[image: VS Azure Tools - Upgrade Project]

Do not apply any changes manually to the definition/configuration/project files!